# Dreamweaver PHP Syntax Error

Tags: php, syntax, dreamweaver

I am new to php so please forgive me if this is a dumb question. I get a syntax error on the line with the div id that says "unexpected <" and another on the line below that saying "unexpected ="

```
<?php 
  if (JRequest::getVar('view') != 'featured') {
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumbs" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
  }
?>
```

These errors go away when my code looks like this:

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view') != 'featured') {?>
  <div id="breadcrumbs">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumbs" style="xhtml" />
  </div>
<?php }?>
```

They way I have learned was you only close the php when you are done so it confuses me a bit. Just wondering if I'm just doing it wrong or this is a weird error in Dreamweaver CC 2017.

Thanks for your time guys!

-Allan

Comment: You cant just put HTML inside of PHP, you need to break out using `?>` and then `<?php` again when you want more PHP.  That's the only way PHP knows what should be evaluated as PHP code.

Comment: ah that makes sense, the examples I have gone through were just php if statements not including html.

Thanks AbraCadaver I figured it was just me lol!